# how to fixed 'Omnet++ with MiXim' errors

Tags: omnet++, mixim

I install Mixim Ver.2.3, but is like there are not compatible please can someone help me, on how to fixed this problem. Am doing my Dissertation No Object Tracking Using WSN

[image: I install Mixim Ver.2.3, but is like there are not compatible please can someone help me, on how to fixed this problem. Am doing my Dissertation No Object Tracking Using WSN]

Comment: I find it hard to help you, based on the question you asked. For helpful tips, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I install Omnet++ 5.0 successful, but when i install MiXim 2.3 it shows errors. so my question is how can i fixed this Mixim problem.

Comment: it looks like you're not linking in the OMNeT++ libraries, or your OMNeT++ version is too new for your MiXiM code. As far as I can tell, MiXiM development stopped in [2011](http://mixim.sourceforge.net/), which probably makes it incompatible with some architectural changes that have happened in OMNeT++ since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use MiXiM you need to install Omnet++ version 4.6.

You need to import MiXiM library, build the project and afterwards you will be able to test some examples contained in MiXiM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your operating system. In linux,after installing Omnet++, you should run `make makefiles` and them `make` commands in MIXIM folder. That arranges MIXIM with Omnet++.

I suggest you study the "install guide" document in Omnetpp folder. Also, the "install" file in Mixim-2.3 folder.